# Scope of variable in Javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

These are the two functions in my program.

Function 1:

```
 var parentLI;    //Global variable so can be accessed in both functions                         

 $(document).on("click", ".addmorebrands", function() {
            parentLI = $(this).closest('li');                            //Will the value of parentLI local to function 1 only ?
            $('#exampleModalCenter').modal('show');
            $('#exampleModalCenter img').click(function() {
                parentdiv = $(this).closest('div.outerdiv');             //Varbiale local to function 1
                parentdiv.addClass('preselect');
                parentdiv.siblings().removeClass('preselect');
                selectedImageSRC = $(this).attr('src');                  //Varbiale local to function 1
            })
        });
```

Function 2:

```
$('#add-image').click(function(){
        parentLI.append('<div class="imagewrap"><img class="images" src="'+selectedImageSRC+'" title="Manual Addition"> <input type="button" class="removediv" value="X" /></div>');
        var imageNameValue = parentLI.children('.imagenames').val();
        var imageTitleValue = parentLI.children('.hoverinformation').val();


        $('#exampleModalCenter').modal('hide');
        parentdiv.removeClass('preselect');          //How am I able to access parentdiv which is local to function 1

    });
```

**Doubts I have regarding scope of variable**

1. The `parentdiv` is defined in `Function1` and will be local to `Function1`. How am I able to access it in `Function2`
2. The `selectedImageSRC` is defined in `Function1` and will be local to `Function1`. How am I able to accesss it in `Function2` In the line `parentLI.append('<div class="imagewrap"><img class="images" src="'+selectedImageSRC+'" title="Manual Addition"> <input type="button" class="removediv" value="X" /></div>');`
3. The variable `parentLI` is declared outside both the functions so it will be global.But its value($(this).closest('li');) is assigned to it in `Function1`.How is that value($(this).closest('li');) accesible in `Function2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you define a variable without using a `var`, `let` or `const` keyword, it is defined in the global namespace (a.k.a. `window`). In contrast to PHP, the variables from the global namespace are automatically available inside functions. That's why `parentdiv` and the other variables are visible in the second function.

```
function test() {
    variable1 = 'foo';
    var variable2 = 'bar';
}

test();
console.log(typeof variable1); // 'string'
console.log(typeof variable2); // 'undefined'
```

Concerning the third question, a variable has the same value everywhere. You defined the variable in the common namespace, so both function see the same one variable which is defined globally, not locally.

Comment: Variable with keyword `var` inside a function makes it local to that function and cant be accessed outside that function but only in that function.But if variable with keyword `var`  declared outside function(in common name space) becomes a global variable and can be accessed anywhere in any function  Correct me if I am wrong

Comment: Its bit strange or maybe since I am new to JS I am feeling it weird to digest

Comment: @NewBie In JS a good practice is always to use a `var`, `let` or `const` keyword to define a variable. In this case a variable will affect the local and child scopes (`{ ... }`) and won't affect parent and sibling scopes.

Comment: Essentially the variables inside a function without keyword `var` are actually global variables then

Comment: @NewBie If you need to define a global variable inside a function, use `window` instead: `window.myVariable = 'foo';`.

Comment: Thanks will use it .But is my understanding in my previous comment correct ?

Comment: @NewBie Correct only for some cases. For example, you define a `myVar` variable in a function without a `var` keyword. If there is no `myVar` variable in the parent scopes, you will make a global variable. Otherwise you will overwrite a variable from a parent scope. Example: `function t1 () { var myVar = 'foo'; function t2 () { myVar = 'bar'; } }` (a global variable is not created).

Comment: As long as no other function has same variable named(when declared without `var` in first function itself) in it that variable's value will remain same as declared in a function.But if any function below it overwrites it it will get overwritten.

Answer (score 2):

1. `parentdiv` isn't declared with the `var` keyword. that's a `js` *hack* to make a variable global from a local block.
   if you change the declaration to:

`var parentdiv = $(this).closest('div.outerdiv');`

you'll find out that it becomes local.

2. same with `selectedImageSRC`
3. if the variable is global, its value can be accessed from every function in the `DOM` regardless of how the value got there. that means that you should be aware of the order of execution

Comment: Suppose that `parentLI` is delcared in common name space as `var parentLI` and  if there were 4 functions which were accessing `parentLI`.Function 1 assigned some value to it and this value will be accessed in function 2.Now function 3 changed the value of `parentLI` then what value will be there in function 4(if `parentLI` is accessed in `function4`) Will it be of Function 1 or that of Function 3

Answer (score 2):

1.parentdiv isn't declare with **var** keyword

```
if you have to use parentdiv out side function 1 than you have to declare that variable globally and use in anywhere in js code of that page
<script>
var parentdiv="";
$(document).ready(function(){

});
</script>
```

you can declare like that for use variable globally in script for all.